# npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE,errno ENOENT & syscall spawn

Tags: node.js, npm, plesk

I am running npm commands under a subdomain folder in a dedicated CentOs7 linux server.but "npm install" command makes some Errors  like:

```
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! fibers@4.0.2 install: `node build.js || nodejs build.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@4.0.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log             ging output above.
```

and if remove fibers dependency there are same errors for core-js package.

and after that in "npm run dev" command i have this

```
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! myappname@1.0.0 dev: `nuxt`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myappname@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I don't have root user permission and i run ssh command with plesk provided options in diffrent node versions and i have same problem in all versions:

```
/opt/plesk/node/9/bin/npm install
/opt/plesk/node/10/bin/npm install
/opt/plesk/node/12/bin/npm install
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/generating-and-locating-npm-debug-log-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after a bit more concentrate on the Error.

some packages like 'fibers' need Compilers to be installed on the OS and in my case the GCC (C/C++ Compiler for Linux) was the solution.

the `sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"` command did it for me.